# java - why do we sometimes need <E> in static method declarations?

Tags: java, eclipse

I get the following error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type E" for the method below:

```
public static void reverse(E[] a) {
       Stack<E> buffer = new Lab8<>(a.length); 

       for (int i=0; i < a.length; i++)
          buffer.push(a[i]);

       for (int i=0; i < a.length; i++)
          a[i] = buffer.pop();
}
```

now I know that doing the following will fix the error, but I don't get the point of < E > (why we need it in this case), and it doesn't make sense to define it in the method like that? I do get how to use it for instance in declaring generic classes and instances, but this is the first time I've seen it used this way...

```
public static <E> void reverse(E[] a) {
       Stack<E> buffer = new Lab8<>(a.length); 

       for (int i=0; i < a.length; i++)
          buffer.push(a[i]);

       for (int i=0; i < a.length; i++)
          a[i] = buffer.pop();
}
```

This is the full code for reference:

```
 package labs;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Lab8<E> implements Stack<E> {

 public static final int CAPACITY=1000;
 private E[] data;
 private int t = -1;
 public Lab8() { this(CAPACITY); }
 public Lab8(int capacity) {
// default array capacity
// generic array used for storage
// index of the top element in stack
// constructs stack with default capacity // constructs stack with given capacity // safe cast; compiler may give warning
   data = (E[ ]) new Object[capacity];

 }
 public int size() { return (t + 1); }
 public boolean isEmpty() { return (t == -1); }
 public void push(E e) throws IllegalStateException {
      if (size() == data.length) throw new IllegalStateException("Stack is full");
      data[++t] = e;
 }

 public E top() {
     if (isEmpty()) return null;
        return data[t];
 }

 public E pop() {
     if (isEmpty( )) return null;
     E answer = data[t];
     data[t] = null;
     t--;
     return answer;
 }

 public static void reverse(E[] a) {
        Stack<E> buffer = new Lab8<>(a.length); 

        for (int i=0; i < a.length; i++)
          buffer.push(a[i]);

        for (int i=0; i < a.length; i++)
          a[i] = buffer.pop();
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
            Integer[] a = {4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42}; // autoboxing allows this 
            String[] s = {"maryam", "ricardo", "Mostafa", "Ahmend", "Hitler"};
            System.out.println("a = " + Arrays.toString(a)); 
            System.out.println("s = " + Arrays.toString(s)); 
            System.out.println("Reversing...");
            reverse(a);
            reverse(s);
            System.out.println("a = " + Arrays.toString(a)); System.out.println("s = " + Arrays.toString(s));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't put that `<E>` in the method declaration, the compiler won't be able to understand if you wanted to make a generics method or if you are trying to reference an actual class named `E` and have just forgotten to import it. 
In absence of the type parameter, the compiler can only assume the second option and complain because it can't find the `E` class anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

The generic parameter `E` is only available for a specific instance hence the compilation error.

The `<E>` within the method signature is used to denote a type parameter, without this the compiler wouldn't know whether `E[] a` is a type parameter or a concrete type declaration.

Answer (score 0):

**`<E>` is required for static methods**, whereas `<E>` is optional for non-static methods.

In a class or interface declaration generic type parameters are non-static: the type parameters refer to specific type declarations of variables or fields (e. g. `List<String> l;` or `List<Integer> l`). In contrast, static methods can be used without a variable/field declaration and therefore the [**Java Language Specification**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/index.html) specifies that the **scope of a class/interface type parameter does not include static methods**. Or in other words, in generic static methods the type parameters must be explicit declared, e. g. `static <E> void foo (E e) {}`.

See [Java Language Specification §8.1.2.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2):

> #### 8.1.2. Generic Classes and Type Parameters
>
> ...
>   **It is a compile-time error to refer to a type parameter of a generic
>   class C in any of the following:**
>   - the declaration of a static member of C (§8.3.1.1, [§8.4.3.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.2), §8.5.1).
>   - ...
>
> #### 8.4.3.2. `static` Methods

#### Examples:

```
public class C<E> {

    // non-static   
    void foo1(E e) {}
    <F> void foo2(F f) {}
    <E> void foo3(E e) {}
//   ^ WARNING: The type parameter E is hiding the type E

    // static
    static <F> void bar1 (F f) {}
    static <E> void bar2 (E e) {}
//  static void bar3 (E e) {}
//                    ^ ERROR: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type E

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // non-static
        C<String> c = new C<>();
        c.foo1("42");
//      c.foo1(42);
//        ^^^^ ERROR: The method foo1(String) in the type C<String> is not applicable for the arguments (int)
        c.foo2("42");
        c.foo2(42);
        c.foo3("42");
        c.foo3(42);

        // static
        C.bar1("42");
        C.bar1(42);
        C.bar2("42");
        C.bar2(42);

    }

}
```